# "finally" for algebraic effects and handlers

Tags: continuations, algebraic-effects

In Java in addition to `catch` there is also `finally`, this is very important to make sure resources get cleaned up. I believe `dynamic-wind` for `call-cc` is similar to this. According to [this](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/implementations.html#dynamic-wind) `dynamic-wind` can be written using delimited continuations. Because algebraic effects can can express delimited continuations, does that mean that we can write a `finally` like construct using algebraic effects and handlers, that allows us to safely handle resources?

Comment: If you have `catch` but not `finally`, you can always write a `catch` block that merely performs cleanup and re-raises the exception. Perhaps something similar could work with algebraic effects? The non-linear use of the continuation could be problematic, though.

Comment: Yes I am worried about the fact that with algebraic effect handlers you can call the continuation zero, one or more times.

Comment: There is a recent arxiv paper by Danel Ahman and Andrej Bauer: https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11629 that describes "runners" which differ from handlers and have an interface that uses "finally" clauses. I'll just leave this as a comment since Andrej is a frequent user here and so is likely to give an answer.